# Offline Interactive Mapping

Tags: google-maps, mapping, offline

I am looking for a good interactive mapping software/suite that will allow me to display polygons over a topography map, and be able to display HTML when a polygon is clicked, for more information. I have looked into Google Maps, but the problem is that this map will be in a static location, without internet.

**Goal**:  Find  a way to make interactive maps offline.

**Researched**: Google Offline caching, but from what i understand, it will not be able to cache an entire country with polygons, and HTML files. I have found GMapCatcher, can anyone verify it caches very well, and in full detail?

Other than that, any suggestions are welcome.

This map will be an interactive map for a WW II exhibit, which will consist of polygons( describing battles and positions), and when clicked on, they are to display some information about the object.

Comment: Is it going to be displayed on a computer or tablet?

Comment: I will say computer for now, but may later be transfered to a tablet.

Comment: GMapCatcher is "dubious" for compliance with the google maps terms of service. See https://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/issues/detail?id=210 for one example. So I'd be thinking of something that has a basemap you can control. After all, topography does change over decades, so you'd ideally be representing what it looked like then, or "then and now".

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tilemill to create your own baselayer,
convert them with mbutils to a folder-Structure
and use a OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ where you point to your local tiles.

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/

https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/XYZ-js.html

works also on mobile devices if you convert your app with something like phonegap to an native app.

Only downside: If your area is relatively large your tiles can consume several MB's of storage (depending on how many zoomlevels need to be available)